SOQL Queries inside Triggers, Coding Standards
Is it good or bad design practice to place SOQL Queries inside Triggers? After a person updates a Quote Object in salesforce,  we want to gather some of its related Account Information, Contacts, Quote Line Items, etc and send it to eventBus. Are there any performance, or scaling issues if I place SOQL queries inside an object Update Triggers? Otherwise I can place these additional queries in the subscriber, instead of the Trigger sender.

SOQL in triggers is fine, it's more about making sure your code is "bulkified" (i.e. don't put queries or dml inside of loops, prefer to write methods that operate on collections instead of single records).
That also goes for publishing platform events with EventBus.publish(). Create all the events you want to publish, and then publish them all at once outside of all loops.
If you're handling the Platform Events in a Platform Event Trigger (i.e. in Apex, inside of Salesforce), then that's still a trigger.
If you're handling Platform Events in some external (to your Salesforce org) system, then querying for that extra data may be less performant because, in addition to the time it takes to run the query, you're also waiting for the API call (initiating the connection + time to return the results). That'd be magnified if you were making API calls to Salesforce one record at a time.

@mattsmith5 Just as a general rule, you shouldn't rely on ChatGPT (or similar tools) for specific information about things that you don't understand. Those tools don't have actual knowledge, they just string together a sequence of words that does a good job at sounding like coherent English (most of the time). This is a perfect example of ChatGPT being mostly full of shit. The "careful consideration" it mentions boils down to what I said in the first part of my answer (don't put queries or dml inside of loops).

hi @DerekF, thanks for the info, can you address some of the points in this article? Appreciate it, trying to learn salesforce and get all points of view, https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D5KX00000KAhOP
